# MATLAB for Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: software-installation, matlab

Which version of MATLAB is suitable for my Computer with these specification

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
CPU: 64 bit machine
Memory: 8 GB RAM.

And from where do I download it?

Comment: Please contact Matlab support about hardware requirements of their proprietary software. They'll be happy to help you as a current or potential future customer.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is proprietary software. You can't install it from standard distribution repository. You can download MATLAB from Mathworks web site (see [this answer](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103682-how-do-i-install-the-matlab-student-version-on-linux) for detail).

Also you may find interesting open source program [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) which compatible with MATLAB in many cases.

Comment: It's worth also mentioning that Octave is available from the standard repositories and can be installed via `sudo apt-get install octave` command

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB is proprietary software owned by MathWorks company. You will have to go to [MathWorks website](http://www.mathworks.com/) and purchase a copy of MATLAB, download their installer, and go from there.

If you are a college student, you can purchase [student version](https://www.mathworks.com/store/link/products/student/SV?s_tid=ac_buy_sv_but1&requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com), either bundled with toolboxes specific for a particular engineering field such as signal processing or control systems, or just get the student version itself. Bundled version is $99 and unbundled is $49 at the time of writing this answer.

What personally I use is release R2016b, student version, also on 16.04 and 64-bit OS. Newest release is R2017, which should work with 16.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

The requirement of MATLAB for Linux OS is cleanly stated in their website.

For Matlab 2017, this can be learnt from here -  https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq.html

Restating keyparts of it below

#### Operating Systems

- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS, and 16.10
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and 7**
- SUSE Linux Enterprise Desktop 12***
- Debian 8.x

#### CPU

- Any Intel or AMD x86-64 processor
- AVX2 instruction set support is recommended
- With Polyspace, 4 cores is recommended

#### Disk space

- 2.2 GB for MATLAB only installation
- 4–6 GB for a typical installation

#### Memory requirement

- Minimum 2GB
- With Simulink, 4 GB is required
- With Polyspace, 4 GB per core is recommended

#### Graphics Card

- No specific graphics card is required. (In normal case)
- Hardware accelerated graphics card supporting OpenGL 3.3 with 1GB GPU memory is recommended.
- Use of vendor-supplied proprietary drivers is strongly recommended. (For example if you have AMD or Nvidia cards, proprietary drivers supplied by these vendors would be best)

If the requirements here seems a bit high, you can download older version of Matlab. The requirements for older version can be found in this page of the same site -  https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html. For example, for Matlab 2016b, the requirements pdf file is this https://www.mathworks.com/content/dam/mathworks/mathworks-dot-com/support/sysreq/files/SystemRequirements-Release2016b_Linux.pdf

And it can be downloaded from https://www.mathworks.com/ site.